# Jenkins Select unique parameter with multiple values

Tags: jenkins

Hello I want the following behaviour.

A want my job to be parametrized. The thing is that I want to select a unique parameter with multiple values.

I have a unique parameter named number with 2 options (1, 2) and then set of values linked to each option:

> Parameter name: var
>
> Options:
>
> 1
>
> 2

Let´s say:

- One set of values:

> - value1: "1.0.0"
> - value2: "myname"
> - value3:"build/libs"

- Another set of values:

> - value1: "2.0.0"
> - value2: "myname2"
> - value3: "var/lib"

In the "Build section" I select "Execute shell" with the following lines:

```
echo ${var.value1}
echo ${var.value2}
echo ${var.value3}
```

So when building the job I would like to select from a dropdown list with 2 values as said above: 1 and 2.

If I select 1, I would like to take the first set of values so that it would dislplay:

```
1.0.0
myname
build/libs
```

On the other hand if I select 2, I would like to display the second set of values:

```
2.0.0
myname2
var/lib
```

I have tried "Extended Choice Parameter plugin" but I don´t know how to manage this situation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to set job parameterized with two options, and just set up variables in the Shell Build step, like this:

```
if [ "$VAR" == "1" ]; then
    value1="1.0.0"
    value2="myname"
    value3="build/libs"
elif [ "$VAR" == "2" ]; then
    value1="2.0.0"
    value2="myname2"
    value3="var/lib"
fi

echo ${var.value1}
echo ${var.value2}
echo ${var.value3}
```